# Storing a HTML OBJECT Array inside Chrome Storage for a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, google-chrome, storage

BACKGROUND:

I'm writing a chrome extension that when you access a certain page it finds all the table rows and then stores them and when you go back it shows you all the new values that have been added.

I want to store an array in storage so that when the user comes back to the page I can access it. Mainly to compare results each time to see if anything has changed.

Example.

```
myArray = [HTML OBJECT, HTML OBJECT, HTML OBJECT];  

on.window.unload {
    Chrome.storage.set(STORE MY ARRAY)
}

on.windows.onload {
    chrome.storage.get(MY STORED ARRAY AND SET TO OLD_myArray[])
}

function compareArrays() {
    TO DO STUFF WITH MY myArray[] and OLD_myArray[]
        e.g. comparing values to see if anything has changed.
}
```

I've tried local Storage but realised that It doesn't store arrays, So moved to Chrome storage.

I would like help getting myArray to store itself on unload and then set itself to OLD_myArray onload, So I can compare the values for the differences. Thanks.

Comment: Did you take a fast look at the documentation? https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage Besides, localStorage stores just strings, that might be your issue. The documentation is extremely clear about how to store key->value pairs anyway, that doesn't really seem you put any effort searching before asking.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `chrome.storage`, you need to use one of two methods:

- `chrome.storage.sync`, which syncs saved data to any browser the user logs into.
- `chrome.storage.local`, which only saves data to the current machine.

As the [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) discusses, `chrome.storage` is implemented with callbacks, not with a return value from the `get` or `set` call itself.

```js
// Save the current myArray value.
chrome.storage.local.set({'storedArray': myArray}, function() {
    console.log(`storedArray now contains ${myArray}.`);
});

// Retrieve the the stored value, defaulting to an empty array.
chrome.storage.local.get({'storedArray': []}, function(data) {
    console.log(`storedArray's value is ${data.storedArray}.`);
});
```

As an aside, it may not be a great idea to attach storage functions to an `unload` event, as the browsing context could terminate before the operation is complete. A browser crash, for instance, wouldn't call the `window.unload` event (this is only one of a number of situations which would interfere with your handler).

Comment: is this possible with an array full of HTML objects?

Comment: @b0nfire It should be possible to store any data type in an array in `chrome.storage`. That being said, if you're only concerned with the contents of certain elements (which it sounds like may be the case), you might consider using [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) to retrieve the HTML structure and content of the element as a string, instead of storing the objects directly.

Comment: If you're simply looking to check for data changes and you know that the structure of the table will be comparable across loads, you could also process the data and store the rows in `chrome.storage` as an array of objects with the column headers as its keys. You could then more easily diff the contents of the recorded table versus the live one, and allow for the exporting of the data in JSON format.